# How to generate empty space in a fo:block if there is no valued in the extracted element?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am using XSL-FO and FOP .95, whenever i write a code in xsl-fo i have to use this statement to generate an empty space:

```
<fo:block>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(Seller_Name)!=''">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Seller_Name)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</fo:block>
```

I dont want to use these choose when conditions to generate an empty space to save the block collapse. is there any function or property which can be used here? I have tried line-feed-treatment and white-space-collapse but it didnt work. Please advise something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are happy with what you have above, why not template it. This would reduce the call to three lines:

```
<xsl:template name="blockwithblank">
    <xsl:param name="field"/>
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="normalize-space($field)!=''">
              <xsl:value-of select="$field"/>
          </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </fo:block>
 </xsl:template>
```

That above is once in the whole stylesheet, then each of the calls is only three lines:

```
  <xsl:call-template name="blockwithblank">
      <xsl:with-param name="field" select="Seller_Name"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
```

I am not sure you can shorten it more than three lines each call.

Comment: You can shorten it considerably by making only the space conditional, since an empty string is empty anyway. I don't think the question is about that, though.

Comment: Great. Not sure in what context you are inserting these, but I usually use <fo:leader/> in lieu of the space character

Answer (score 1):

Use two templates: one for the regular case and the other, with a higher priority, for the empty case:

```
<xsl:template match="Seller_Name">
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Seller_Name[normalize-space() = '']" priority="5">
    <fo:block>&#160;</fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Your XSLT would need to have a xsl:apply-templates at the appropriate point, but it would make the current template shorter.

If you're doing this a lot with multiple elements, you could match on multiple elements in each of these templates and save a lot of repetition.

Comment: what if i change the priorty? will it make any difference?

Comment: Only if there's already another template that has a higher priority that's currently being used instead.  That second `xsl:template` already has a higher intrinsic priority than the first, so in this case, setting `@priority` just makes it more obvious to the human reader what you want to happen.